# Insert several thousand rows into table with values from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a PostgreSQL database with 4 tables - Table A, B, C and D. Table A has three columns which are IDs from the other three tables.

Something like this:

```
TABLE A
--------------------------
| id | B_id | C_id | D_id |
---------------------------
```

I already have several thousand rows of data in tables B, C, D, and now want to generate an insert script for table A, by selecting data from the other 3 based on some conditions.

I tried as follows:

```
INSERT INTO A (B_id, C_id, D_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM B WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM C WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM D WHERE CONDITION)),((SELECT id FROM B WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM C WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM D WHERE CONDITION)),((SELECT id FROM B WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM C WHERE CONDITION), (SELECT id FROM D WHERE CONDITION)), ....;
```

However, with a big amount of rows this takes ages and then fails.

I am wondering if I'm doing this right and if not, what would be the most efficient way of achieving what I want.

More detailed info and example data

```
Accounts
---------------------------------------------
| id | firstName | lastName | email (unique)|
---------------------------------------------
  1     Account      One      aone@email.com
```

```
Groups
----------------------
| id | name (unique) |
----------------------
  1      Group One
```

```
Titles
----------------------
| id | name (unique) |
----------------------
  1      Title One
```

Table A then contains an id from each of these as mentioned:

```
A
------------------------------------
| id | accountId | groupId | titleId
------------------------------------
  1        1          1          1
```

For each account (each unique email), I programmatically generate an insert statement

```
INSERT INTO A (accountId, groupId, titleId)
VALUES (
    (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE email = {EMAIL}),
    (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE name = {groupName}),
    (SELECT id FROM titles WHERE name = {titleName}))
```

As mentioned there will be several thousand (aprox 15000) insert statements generated. The condition values are programmatically added from some parsed data in my script.

The select statements will always return exactly one row because where conditions are done on columns with unique constraints. Therefore each account email should have exactly one combination of account + group + title in table A.

Comment: The subqueries in your `VALUES` clause are not logically well defined, because we don't really even know if they all would generate the same number of records.  Please add sample data for the tables.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a better explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: I added some extra info in the OP.

Comment: Is there any indexes/triggers on table `A`?

Comment: No indexes or triggers

Answer (score 1):

Create single temporary table for all `{EMAIL}, {groupName}, {titleName}` triplets and fill it. Lets say it would be:

```
create temp table filler (
    email text,
    group_name text,
    title_name text);

insert into filler values
    ('email1', 'group1', 'title1'),
    ('email2', 'group2', 'title2'),
    ....
    ('emailn', 'groupn', 'titlen');
```

Or use [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Then insert values in single statement using it:

```
insert into A (accountId, groupId, titleId)
select a.id, g.id, t.id
from
    filler as f
        left join accounts as a on (f.email = a.email)
        left join groups as g on (f.group_name = g.name)
        left join titles as t on (f.title_name = t.name);
```

PS: Indexes on `accounts.email`, `groups.name` and `titles.name` could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your values expression is set up to insert exactly *one* row.  Each subquery is a scalar subquery that can return at most one row.  The overall query will fail, if any of them return more than one row.

Perhaps you want a Cartesian Product of the values returned by all subqueries.  If so, use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO A (B_id, C_id, D_id) 
    SELECT b.id, c.id, d.id
    FROM (SELECT id FROM B WHERE CONDITION) b CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT id FROM C WHERE CONDITION) c CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT id FROM D WHERE CONDITION) d;
```

Run the `SELECT` first to be sure it generates the rows you intend to insert.

Comment: The select statements will always return exactly one row. I added some extra info in the OP.

Comment: @rok . . . The title of your question suggests otherwise, which is why I answered.

Comment: Yeah, I apologize if the title is a bit confusing. Hopefully I explained well enough with my post update.